# When changing a password via PowerShell, is there a way to bypass the prompt that asks for the existing password?

Tags: powershell, passwords, automation, powershell-ise

Below I have some code that will ask the user for their admin credentials and if they're within that domain, the script proceeds and then resets the password of a user of their choosing. It works...but, the one I'm writing this for wants to be able to bypass the prompt that comes up by default asking for the user's existing password before it gets reset. He doesn't know everyone's password and would rather not dig for it. I cannot find ANYTHING on how to do this online. Does anyone have suggestions? I have my code below and the lower half is just the addition of a text box so you can ignore it. Thanks!

```
# Function to generate a random password
function Generate-RandomPassword {
    param (
        [int]$Length = 12
    )
    
    $charPool = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!@#$%^&*()-_=+[]{}|;:',.<>/?"
    $password = ""
    
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $Length; $i++) {
        $password += $charPool[(Get-Random -Minimum 0 -Maximum $charPool.Length)]
    }
    
    return $password
}

# Prompt user to enter admin credentials
$AdminUsername = Read-Host "Enter the admin username"
$AdminPassword = Read-Host "Enter the admin password" -AsSecureString
$AdminCredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($AdminUsername, $AdminPassword)

# Verify if the provided admin is in the domain
$AdminExists = Get-ADUser -Filter {SamAccountName -eq $AdminUsername} -Credential $AdminCredential -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

if ($AdminExists) {
    # Prompt user to enter a username
    $Username = Read-Host "Enter the username for which you want to change the password"

    # Check if the Active Directory user exists
    $UserExists = Get-ADUser -Filter {SamAccountName -eq $Username} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    if ($UserExists) {
        # Generate a random password
        $RandomPassword = Generate-RandomPassword

        # Change the user's password
        $SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $RandomPassword -Force
        Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity $Username -NewPassword $SecurePassword -Credential $AdminCredential

        # Output the random password in a text box
        Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework

        $TextBox = New-Object Windows.Forms.TextBox
        $TextBox.Multiline = $true
        $TextBox.Text = $RandomPassword
        $TextBox.SelectAll()

        $Form = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form
        $Form.Text = "Random Password"
        $Form.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size(300, 100)
        $Form.Controls.Add($TextBox)

        $Button = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button
        $Button.Text = "Copy Password"
        $Button.Add_Click({
            $TextBox.SelectAll()
            $TextBox.Copy()
            $Button.Text = "Copied!"
        })
        $Form.Controls.Add($Button)

        $Form.ShowDialog()

        # Log the operation in a text file
        $LogEntry = "Date: $(Get-Date), Admin: $AdminUsername, User: $Username"
        $LogPath = "C:\Temp"
        Add-Content -Path $LogPath -Value $LogEntry
    } else {
        Write-Host "User '$Username' not found in Active Directory. Please enter a valid username."
    }
} else {
    Write-Host "Invalid admin credentials. Please make sure the provided admin is in the domain."
}
```

Comment: You want to _reset_ the password, not change it. There might be implications, but I cannot verify them.

Comment: I hope your admins don't know the user's passwords, and have NO WAY of learning them. If passwords are stored anywhere, that is terri-bad and should be stopped right away. Set-AdAccountPassword does not need the previous account password. I don't see where this script prompts for an existing password.

Comment: If the system is prompting for a username and password outside whatever this script is doing, that may be because the script needs to be run as admin, which isn't super easy if you're already inside the script. Optimally, you open PowerShell AS the admin account, and that's all the validation you need, so you get rid of all the intro stuff on this, require the script to be run as administrator, and then just leave the stuff where you're choosing the user account.

Comment: @music2myear By default it will ask because you're correct, I didn't put anything in there that should ask for the existing password. It just happens by default.

Comment: @DanielB sorry for my choice of words. My admin would like to change the password of any user, not reset it.

Comment: It’s not about your choice of words. If you want to _reset_, you _must_ specify `-Reset` on `Set-ADAccountPassword`. Have you tried that yet?

Comment: @DanielB Oh I see what you're saying. Yes, I did the -reset parameter with ADAccountPassword and that did indeed work. It no longer asks for a password. Had my admin try it out and it worked like a charm! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Set-ADAccountPassword` line is missing the `-reset` parameter.

If you have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/set-adaccountpassword?view=windowsserver2022-ps you'll see that "Specifies to reset the password on an account. When you use this parameter, you must set the NewPassword parameter. You do not need to specify the OldPassword parameter."

So your line of code needs to be

```
Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity $Username -Reset -NewPassword $SecurePassword -Credential $AdminCredential
```

Answer (score 1):

You may **reset** an AD user password without asking for the
old password by first storing the password in a variable and
then using it in the cmdlet,
like this:

```
$Pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString "MyNewPassword@123" -AsPlainText -Force 
Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity AbbeyWarren -NewPassword $Pwd -Reset
```

Source :
[Reset Password via Set-ADAccountPassword Poweshell Cmdlet](https://blog.netwrix.com/2023/03/24/set-adaccountpassword-powershell-cmdlet/).

Comment: My admin will be using this on many accounts. If this was just happening with one account, I see how this could be the way.

Comment: I haven't understood why it can't apply to multiple accounts.

Comment: @harrymc - The author is already using the method you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

> Below I have some code that will ask the user for their admin credentials and if they're within that domain, the script proceeds and then resets the password of a user of their choosing. It works...but, the one I'm writing this for wants to be able to bypass the prompt that comes up by default asking for the user's existing password before it gets reset.
>
> To be clear the Administrator would like to change the password of any user, not reset it.

What you want is impossible. The only way to change your password is to know (and provide) your old password. Any other method that doesn’t require the existing password actually will reset the password. If you are using EFS this will disable access to any encrypted files permanently unless the certificate is exported prior to performing the past reset.

Furthermore, if your administrator knows a user accounts password, they are doing everything wrong. The only thing an Administrator should be able to do is reset the accounts password.  Contrary to what this Administrator might have claimed, on Windows an Administrator, does NOT have the ability to view a user’s password or otherwise determine what the password is.

A Windows Administrator can always reset the password to a Windows account without knowing the existing password but per the warning displayed access to encrypted files will be loss unless the certificate is stored on the AD domain server or otherwise exported.

To be clear Set-ADAccountPassword can be used to **reset** a user’s password, but it is not possible, to change the password without knowing the existing password.  Only **changing** a user’s password prevents the loss of access to encrypted files.

Running just a single instance of Set-ADAccountPassword and ConvertTo-SecureString by passing a variable against a test account on my domain successfully reset the password to the user. However, I must reiterate the fact, this reset the password but it did not **change** the user’s password. While technically performing a password reset does change the password, a password reset and changing your account’s password, are two entirely different things.

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle - That article only applies or appears to apply to the credential manager not an user on a AD domain. My statement I feel is still accurate, you cannot change a user’s password, without knowing the existing password unless you reset the password. I suspect the author just has a PowerShell syntax error and/or the script isn’t being ran as an Administrator. The author also wants to specifically change the user’s password without supplying the existing password (or resetting the password) which strictly speaking is impossible

Comment: Hmmm, I see. As simple as the topic sounds, I don't think I ever knew the real difference between resetting a password and changing it. I always assumed they were the same thing. That is excellent information and I thank you for it!